# What are these things in php? Ex: $_COOKIE[], $_POST[], etc

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, syntax

I'm just starting out, so please forgive if this is a silly question.

I'm learning by reading a book and watching a video series that may be slightly out-dated.

The instructions given in certain cases where more than one page is involved use regular variable syntax, but that syntax does not work unless I use the syntax mentioned in the title of this post.

**Example from the video includes:**

Page 1:

```
<?php

setcookie("color","blue");

?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php

echo $color;

?>
```

This does not work for me.  However, if I change things using the other syntax, it does work.

**Example from changes to variable syntax that makes it work:**

Page 1:

```
<?php

setcookie("color","blue");

?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php

echo $_COOKIE["color"];

?>
```

So my question is, what is this syntax (ex: $_COOKIE["color"]) that I am using? What is it called and what/how does it work exactly?

I realize this has something to do with sessions, but am too novice to understand beyond that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your book is assuming that [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is turned on. This is a feature that introduced lots of security issues and has been something to avoid for many, many years. I strongly recommend getting a better guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called Superglobals, they are "special" variables that are always defined.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

The first example can work if the evil, evil register_globals is enabled:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.registerglobals.php

If you are learning PHP from a source that is using register_globals, I suggest you find another source.

Comment: `Magic Quotes`?  Don't you mean `Register Globals`?

Comment: @Rocket: Yes thank you (and duskwuff), I'm a little drunk this morning I think... Nathan: Avoid Magic Quotes as well :)

Answer (score 3):

The first type of syntax, where you just "find the variables already there" is dependent on a PHP feature called [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). This feature was introduced a long time ago as a convenience to novices, but it has been the source of *many* security issues and has been deprecated for some time now (in fact, support for this mode has been totally removed in the upcoming version PHP 5.4). For a very quick overview, read "[how does register_globals affect me?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.register-globals)" in the FAQ.

The other way of accessing "environment" variables (i.e. those originating from the current HTTP request or the server setup) is by accessing the [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variables; this page is also linked to from the register globals piece above.

**If you are reading tutorials that depend on register globals being active you should *immediately* stop reading them and find better and more recent material.**

Comment: Real question: What *is* a good source for new users to learn PHP? I'm disappointed to say I don't know of any offhand.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the example does not work because it is *outdated*. In PHP, there is a setting called [`register_globals`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/security.registerglobals.php) which makes this feature work, but it is not recommended to use it.

The syntax you are talking about (`$_COOKIE["color"]`) is the syntax to get the element of an [(associative) array](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31840&seqNum=3). [`$_COOKIE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) itself is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array, and it always stores the values  of cookies that were included in the HTTP request.

Sessions is something else, cookies can be used to maintain a session.

Answer (score 0):

These are called [Superglobals](http://php.net/superglobals). They are global arrays that are available anywhere, without explicitly defining them using `global()`. There are sevearl available, for cookies, uploaded files, POST variables, etc.

For more information, it's probably best to refer to the PHP manual: http://php.net/superglobals.